# Graph theory problem hint needed

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So the problem goes like this:
There is a $n×n$ ($n$ is odd) chessboard and every tile has 1 coin. Now every coin is shifted up,down, left or right. Find the range of values of n for which there is a configuration such that each tile has only 1 coin.
Note: every coin can be shifted only once. And diagonal shifts are not allowed.

Please mark solutions as spoilers. I need only a hint.

Comment: What are tiles in this context? Connections of horizontal or vertical neighbors?

Comment: Tiles like in a chessboard. Each coin can be shifted to its horizontal or vertical neighbours

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Observe the number of coins on black and the number of coins on white unit squares.

Comment: So if there is an n×n board, n is odd. Then there are (n²-1)/2 and (n²+1)/2 coins in black and white tiles, since every black shifts to white and white shifts to black, the two are not equal hence a configuration with odd n doesnt exist

Comment: That is correct.